# Javascript detect when page goes

Tags: javascript, html, dom

There is a way to detect when the page is being redirected?

Example, I put a timeout for X seconds and if the page wasn't redirected (the user still in the page) it will kill the timer except if the page is being redirect... because some redirections can be freeze (delay, lazy)... so it will re-program the timer instead of kill it...

the readystate will change if the page is on a redirect?

How to detect if the page is on a redirect using javascript?

Thanks

Comment: `onbeforeunload` event is available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  return 'Dialog text here.';
};
```

this function fires when the user is leaving the page, but it is very limited in what can be done in it.  For example you cant fire an ajax call and wait for a return in this function.

Read more here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: Thank you! It has satisfied what i needed!